# Remote EJB Lookup via JNDI on Jboss EAP 6.4

Tags: java-8, jboss7.x, jndi, ejb-3.1, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to run the ejb-remote example from here: [Jboss eap quickstart](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/6.4.x/ejb-remote)

I don't see any issues when I run the server and client on the same machine. However there are issues if the client is executed from a different machine than on server.

I'm assuming the examples provided by jboss team should be working out of the box. I also read article on  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI and various online blogs. Please let me know if I am missing anything obvious. Trying to get the remote client working for couple of days now. :(

ENV:
Server deployed on Jboss EAP 6.4. JDK/JAVA version 8.

Stack trace:

```
java.io.EOFException: XNIO000812: Connection closed unexpectedly
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState$UpgradeResultListener.handleEvent(HttpUpgrade.java:416)
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState.flushUpgradeChannel(HttpUpgrade.java:369)
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState.access$900(HttpUpgrade.java:165)
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState$ConnectionOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpUpgrade.java:340)
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState$ConnectionOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpUpgrade.java:320)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$ConnectHandle.handleReady(WorkerThread.java:324)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:559)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:416)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.EndpointPool$PooledEndpoint.connect(EndpointPool.java:192)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.NetworkUtil.connect(NetworkUtil.java:153)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.NetworkUtil.connect(NetworkUtil.java:133)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:78)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionManager.getConnection(RemotingConnectionManager.java:51)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:161)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:118)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:47)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:281)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:291)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.client.RemoteEJBClient.invokeStatelessBean(RemoteEJBClient.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.client.RemoteEJBClient.main(RemoteEJBClient.java:38)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:jboss-ejb-remote-server-side, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@6eebc39e
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:798)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.client.RemoteEJBClient.invokeStatelessBean(RemoteEJBClient.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.client.RemoteEJBClient.main(RemoteEJBClient.java:38)
```

**UPDATES 04/29:**

*JBOSS Startup log snippets:*

```
9:42:56,600 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
09:42:56,978 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : **http-/0.0.0.0:8080**
09:42:57,010 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: **http-/0.0.0.0:8080**
09:42:57,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
09:42:57,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/deployments/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/deployments
09:42:57,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
09:42:57,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100:Listening on **0.0.0.0:4447**
```

*Netstat output:*

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2917/java

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4447            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2917/java

Comment: Check the entry for remote.connection.default.host name in your  jboss-ejb-client.properties file

Comment: Did you bind your JBoss to 0.0.0.0 in order allow remote connections? And how are you calling your EJB?

Comment: @ aribeiro: Yes, I am binding to 0.0.0.0. Updated the original post with the jboss startup log snippets showing the binding address.

Comment: @Sampada: Yes, properties file has been edited to change the host. I have verified I can connect to the host and port via telnet.

Comment: @userful: Did you find any solution for the above issue. I am also facing issue to lookup remote EJB 3.0 call which are deployed on Jboss EAP 6.3.

Comment: @Gdangi Yes. Look at the below answer and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @useful: I have added same properties and configuration either it is not working. I am accessing it from a Standalone java application???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few issues caused the problem.

1. Port should be 4447, the one in the project on jboss is 8080.
2. one should add user via JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh and add it to the
   jboss-ejb-client.properties as below.

   remote.connection.default.username=user2
   remote.connection.default.password=password12(
3. Use the correct version of client. In my case I was using 6.4 version of server and 7.0.X version of client.